# how can make multiple project just in an apk file

Tags: android

I would like an Android build system procedure, command line or Eclipse, to generate several .apk files from a single source codebase. Some common reasons for this - having specific versions for markets with different requirements or a free and paid version.

Comment: I think any program with sufficient permissions will receive BOOT_COMPLETED regardless of where the program is located. So, you, probably, can put everything into a single project on external storage

Comment: I need when my device rebooted service call again. I programmed it but works on phone memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Activity-alias in manifest file to launch multiple apks from single apk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test "
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/images"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:logo="@drawable/images">
    <activity
        android:name="com.mmx.mccandmnc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Alias activity used to set the wallpaper on Home. The alias is used
         simply to have a different label. -->
    <activity-alias android:name="WallpaperActivity"
        android:targetActivity="LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_set_wallpaper">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: tnx, can i generate them so that one of them install on external storage and other project install on phone memory?

Comment: Soheila, there is a tag in <manifest>, which is android:installLocation="internalOnly", but it will store the entire application where you want it to store.

Comment: tnx a lot, can you give me your email address? i have very questions :(

Comment: yeah sure, vchopra.2710@icloud.com

Comment: tnx, please visit this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android       this is my problem too, but user3439968 answerd to it and is his answer 1.Install your app to internal storage
2.Instal another small app in internal storage. This app recieves BOOT_COMPLETE and run second app on external storage.

Comment: i want to my project install on external memory and when device rebooted sevice run again, he said : 2.Instal another small app in internal storage. This app recieves BOOT_COMPLETE and run second app on external storage.

Comment: Soheila, have to run for a urgent meeting. Will come and revert you back.

Comment: if is possible visit this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816921/how-to-use-service-and-broadcast-receiver